# Are there any alternate eyepieces for people with glasses?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d5100, viewfinder, nikon-d3200

Any recommendations for an alternate DK20 eyepiece for a Nikon D3200 or D5100 that gives a better visual for wearers of glasses? Amazon has many but the reviews are all over the place. My glasses keep me from getting my eye close enough to the viewfinder to see the full frame.

Thanks!

Comment: This might be an interesting reading for you: [Does wearing glasses hinder one from becoming a good photographer?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7104/does-wearing-glasses-hinder-one-from-becoming-a-good-photographer)

Comment: I'm a glasses wearer and simply leave the eyepiece off. Always have.

Comment: Is your prescription outside of the diopter range of the camera?

Comment: @Itai - fiddling about taking off and putting on glasses repeatedly is *not* something anyone wants to do if they don't have to. Ever.

Comment: I am not sure about Nikon, however I know Canon does offer eyepieces with an extended rubber hood, as well as an additional diopter, for people who wear glasses. I used to use one, but I did not like how the dipoter lens in the eyepiece worked...it shrunk the size of the viewfinder image, which made it harder to detect focus. These days, I try to slip in some contacts whenever I head out to do photography...just results in a far superior experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that something like this: [http://www.amazon.com/Hoodman-Glasses-Hoodeye-Eyepiece-Cameras/dp/B007NKPSFW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007NKPSFW) tends to do the job.

It's really just a simple idea. An enlarged eyepiece to cover the eyeglass lens. I bet it wouldn't be to hard to fashion something yourself. :D

Comment: but seriously, if at all possible I'd use contacts. You really can't beat them when using your camera.

Comment: I ended up just upgrading to a full-frame camera; FF viewfinders are much larger and easier to look through.